# How to get z3 in pycharm?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, z3, z3py

I just thought I should try out pycharm and z3 theorem prover but I am having a hard time setting it up.

**Method 1**
I am running Windows 8, and my first try was to install the z3 package via pycharm (package z3-solver in Settings -> Project Interpreter). This however fails with the final lines:

```
    Remark: to open a Visual Studio Command Prompt, go to: "Start > All Programs > Visual Studio > Visual Studio Tools"
    Building Z3
    error: [WinError 2] Det går inte att hitta filen

    ----------------------------------------

Command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\z3-solver\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-1qzhvlrz-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\z3-solver\
```

**Method 2**
So I downloaded and unpacked z3 and added `%\bin\python\z3` to Interpreter Paths. Now pycharm sees the z3 library and can povide completion. However when I try to run my pythonscript containing `import z3` I receive this ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import z3
  File "...\z3-4.5.0-x64-win\bin\python\z3\z3.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import z3core
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Isn't the z3 python folder seen as a package? (It contains a `__init__.py` file.)

Comment: Is it possible that you tell me how I manually add z3 library and where exactly? Pycharm installs it not fully so methods are not getting recognized. I tried millions of work but still no use. I have downloaded and unzipped z3, what now?